# Disable text box using class name in Javascript

Tags: javascript, getelementsbyclassname

I have **HTML**

```
Name 1:<input type="text" class="one" id="mytext">
<button onclick="disfunction()"></button>
```

**Javascript**

```
function disfunction(){
document.getElementsByClassName("one").disabled = true;
}
```

But the text box is still enabled. How can I **disable** `text box` using the **classname** in **JAVASCRIPT**.

Using id I can do this. Also using jquery.

But I need a solution using `Javascript` and `classname`.

Comment: why of all use class than id?

Answer (score 12):

[`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByClassName) return a list of elements, you need to loop througth it to disable each element :

```
var cells = table.getElementsByClassName("one"); 
for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) { 
    cells[i].disabled = true;
}
```

JSFIDDLE : http://jsfiddle.net/7L14zaha/1/

Answer (score 5):

You may try this, and I bet is what you are looking at.

```
function disfunction(){
document.getElementsByClassName("one")[0].disabled = true;
}
```

JSFiddle :- [Disable on click.](http://jsfiddle.net/tayhaithian/x92Lcc6g/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Mozilla [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) states that:

> elements is a live HTMLCollection of found elements.

So you have to iterate through the result of getElementsByClassName.

```
var testElements = document.getElementsByClassName('class-name-here');
var testDivs = Array.prototype.filter.call(testElements, function(testElement){
    testElement.disabled = true;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

#### 2023 Update

I'm sure this is answered elsewhere, but the following is a good answer with ES6:

```
document.querySelectorAll(".class-name").forEach(element => element.disabled = true);
```